# TitanDB on Amazon EMR

Tags: hbase, emr, titan

I'm trying to run TitanDB (0.54) on Amazon EMR (2.4 + 0.94.18). When I'm trying to connect with gremlin it gets stuck.

```
]$ bin/gremlin.sh

```
     \,,,/
     (o o)
```

-----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open("hbase:localhost")
```

If I look into HBase logs I can see something is happening until I kill gremlin. The log is being filled with:

`14:23:47.913 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39c zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:47.913 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39c zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.114 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39d zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.114 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39d zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.315 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39e zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.315 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39e zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.516 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39f zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.516 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x39f zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.717 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a0 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.717 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a0 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.918 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a1 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:48.918 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a1 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.119 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a2 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.119 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a2 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.320 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a3 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.320 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a3 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.521 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - Processing request:: sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a4 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server
14:23:49.521 [SyncThread:0] DEBUG o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor - sessionid:0x14d2975bed7003b type:getData cxid:0x3a4 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/meta-region-server`

This is the first run and I'm assuming Titan is trying to build a table but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to recompile Titan with `hbase` instead of `hbase-client` version `0.94.18`